# Is this a proximal deictic?

Tags: deixis

"In all my dreams, I saw **him** drowning"

I think it is, thoughts?

Comment: No. _Him_ is simply a personal pronoun. Deixis has to do with place, time, and circumstances of an utterance. Words like _here, this, now_ express proximal deixis. For details, see the [Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html).

Comment: @John:  In the first of those texts, I like the bit about three ways ***may*** can be used. ***Epistemic*** *(It may rain later)*, ***pragmatic*** *(You may go now)*, and ***magic*** *(May you rot in Hell)*. Is the name for that last category (still) widely recognized by you and your peers?

Comment: The first lecture is a real classic. There's probly a latin name for magic _may_, but I'm too lazy to make it up; I prefer Fillmore's term. It's much more descriptive and memorable.

Comment: @ John Lawler,  If poetry is a performative art, *him* w’d be a pronoun, nothing deictic.  But if poetry is a shared experience, then wouldn’t “him drowning” be as deictic as “is *this* a dagger?” or “Look on *this*… and on *this*.”? (only four more days for magic May)

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem the dream state? you could cover that by describing the status of ***him*** as
*Oneiric proximal deixis.*

Comment: It is from the poem "Dulce Et Decorum Est". So yes, I could use that I suppose - it was the term I was looking for actually, thanks.

Comment: It's all Greek to me.  Really astonishing what heights grammar explanations can reach. The sentence structure is simple, but it would take an hour to explain those complicated and superfluous Greek/Latin terms. Academic jargon without value.

Comment: @rogermue don't blame the grammarians; John Lawler's agrees with you.  I am an epistemologist wanting to understand how "Dulce and Decorum Est" works.  It does work im-mediately: we both agree.  But to find out how it does, first it is worth translating the Latin title. It also seems worth analysing what is changed by putting the Chlorine gas attack into a dream  (oneiric).